# Unexpected logout while working in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: 14.04, logout

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Until that day everything had been working fine. But today I've got an error. Every time I started Idea (14.04) it was working for a some period of time and then unexpected system logout happened.

Some details:

- Sometimes it possible to track the problem appearence: Idea starts to repaint windows with errors and newly opened windows has no content. At this moment it is possible to close Idea and prevent logout;
- I checked xorg log for "segmentation faults" records and didn't find a signle one;
- In this morning there was some regular system update without reset;
- I tried to instal and use new version of Idea (15), but the problem didn't disappear. Althogh, the new version was working for a longer period of time before logout;
- I found java_error_in_IDEA error log that included such fragment:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xa734795d, pid=6272, tid=1925831488

**Edit:** Set up Eclipse Mars. It is working just fine but sometimes some window repainting problem appears that does not lead to a logout.
 
I also try the approach that is described in http://mortalpowers.com/news/quick-fix-buttons-stay-depressed-in-eclipse-and-other-gtk-applications-under-karmic-with-kde#.VjulV78_56J but it does not help.

How to prevent this annoying logout? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last regular update the problem has disappeared. Video drivers also have been updated so I think the problem was over there.